# Postgresql Date diff

Tags: postgresql, date-arithmetic

I can not get the difference in date from the previous reading.  Please help why won't this run

```
   alter table p.prodcution
   add Hourly_Rate double precision
   from p.production
   extract (epoch from (p.reported_date -
   (lag(p.reported_date) over (partition by well_id order by p.reported_date))
   ))/3600 AS Hourly_Rate
    ;
```

Comment: You can't `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN` and run a query at the same time. Also you did not actually use `ADD COLUMN` so that portion would not work even without the query.

Comment: Alter table public.production add column hourly_rate date
 extract(epoch(public.reported_date -
              (lag(public.reported_date) over (partition by public.well_id order by public.reported_date))
  ))/3600 AS hourly_rate
  from public.production
;

Comment: Is this closer...I am so lost

Comment: No you can't use a query to populate a field in `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN`.

Comment: See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Untested procedure. Read comments in line. This assumes information about primary key.

```
--Step 1. Add column to table
ALTER TABLE 
   p.production
ADD COLUMN 
   hourly_rate double precision;
--Step 2. Verify query. 
SELECT
   extract (epoch from (p.reported_date -
   (lag(p.reported_date) over (partition by well_id order by p.reported_date))
   ))/3600 AS Hourly_Rate
FROM 
  production
--Step 3. Update column
UPDATE 
   production
SET 
   (hourly_rate) = 
(SELECT
   extract (epoch from (p.reported_date -
   (lag(p.reported_date) over (partition by well_id order by p.reported_date))
   ))/3600 AS Hourly_Rate
FROM 
  production AS p
WHERE
    p.id = production.id)
```

You may need to modify to get the `WHERE` clause correct. Or you could add the schema for the table to your question.

Comment: So I went down a completely different path.  This code runs now I just have to change it to the difference in hours.  Let me know if I am way off base I am new to PostgreSQL and have been thrown in the deep end.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Select
well_id,
reported_date,
lag (reported_date,1) over (
partition by well_id
order by well_id
) AS hour_rate
from 
public.production;

Comment: Add your changes as formatted code to your question. Making people dig through comments for information(especially updated info) will narrow the responses you get.  While you are at it add to your question an example of what information you want returned and what is being returned as well as example of the data you are starting with.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback this is my first day using Stack overflow.  I will do better in the future.  Thank you again